# Modbus and the Sunny Boy

Tags: inverter, modbus

I am using libmodbus to connect to the a SunnyBoy 2.5 inverter. I make the connection as follows:

```
#include <modbus/modbus.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main()
{
    modbus_t *mb;
    uint16_t tab_reg[32];
    int rc;
    int socket;

    mb = modbus_new_tcp("192.168.100.1", 502);
    if (mb == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to allocate libmodbus context\n.");
        return -1;
    }

    if (modbus_connect(mb) == -1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Connection failed: %s\n",
                modbus_strerror(errno));
        modbus_free(mb);
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        socket = modbus_tcp_listen(mb, 1);
        if (socket == -1)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Socket problem: %s\n", modbus_strerror(errno));
        }
        modbus_tcp_accept(mb, &socket);
        printf("Connection successful.\n");
    }
}
```

When I attempt to listen on the socket (modbus_tcp_listen), it gives me a "permission denied" error. How does one gain permission to the SunnyBoy to talk Modbus to it / how do you implement that in the code?

Comment: Do you think that lot of people on this forum know about libmodbus library and your platform (that you didn't describe) to help you? Further, a modbus is a protocol of numbers, so where did you get the "permisson denied" as the modbus hasn't this feature.

Comment: What does the manual for the device say?

Answer (score 1):

You're getting this message because modbus uses port 502. In Unix port numbers below 1024 require root access, so try using

```
sudo bash
```

To get a root shell and give it a try.
You'd also be better off using a scripting language that has a modbus library. This will let you produce fast prototypes with your Sunny Boy.

Comment: For example, see https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-modbus for a node.js library for javascript.